# Выходит ошибка при наисании кода с помощью json

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def bonus(ctx):
    with open('economy.json','r') as f:
        money = json.load(f)

    if not str(ctx.author.id) in money:
      money[str(ctx.author.id)] = {}
      money[str(ctx.author.id)][money] = 0

      if not str(ctx.author.id) in queue:
        emded = discord.Embed(description = '**{ctx.author.id}** Вы получили свои **5000**' )
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        money[str(ctx.author.id)][money] += 5000
        queue.append(str(ctx.author.id))
        with open('economy.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(money,f)
        await asyncio.sleep(24*60)
        queue.remove(str(ctx.author.id))
      if str(ctx.author.id) in queue:
        emded = discord.Embed(description = '**{ctx.author.id}** Вы уже  получили свои **5000**' )
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Выходит ошибка

```
File "C:\Users\263\Desktop\BotTest\main.py", line 70, in bonus
    money(str(ctx.author.id))[money] = 0
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: **1.** Ошибка не в этом куске данных, т.к. в ошибке такая строка `money(str(ctx.author.id))[money] = 0`, а ее нет в вашем примере **2.** И правильная ошибка, у вас там словарь `money`, а у него круглые скобки вызываете, хотя это не функция. Явна опечатка, т.к. должны быть квадратные скобки **3.** В вашем коде есть правильное решение `money[str(ctx.author.id)][money] = 0`

Comment: Кст, а зачем вы id приводите к строке? Ключом и числа могут быть. Да даже если так **нужно**, не вижу причины везде сувать `str(ctx.author.id)`, сделайте выше переменную и в нее положите :)